# SQL query using SUM gworking only on 1 row

Tags: sql

I am currently learning the basics of SQL. I have tried this query but the result happened to work for only one of the rows (FireBow). How do I fix this?

```
CREATE TABLE store (id_prod INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, prod TEXT, price REAL, q REAL);
INSERT INTO store (prod, price, q) VALUES ("DragonSword", 1500.0, 4.0);
INSERT INTO store (prod, price, q) VALUES ("MagicOrb", 950.0, 7.0);
INSERT INTO store (prod, price, q) VALUES ("FireBow", 500.0, 5.0);
UPDATE store SET q=q-3 WHERE prod="FireBow";

SELECT prod, price, q, ((price*q)/SUM(price*q)) AS prec_worth 
FROM store;
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? What output do you want?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (Your code is invalid standard SQL)

Comment: Which of the queries? What are you defining as "works"?   Are you saying you are only getting one row from the SELECT?    Are you positive that the CREATE and UPDATE are working as expected?  Try making a minimal example with simple data, show your expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using **group by** statement then it will show only one record.
Instead of using **SUM** directly in query. Use below one with sub query .

```
SELECT prod, price, q, ((price*q)/(select sum(price*q) from store s)) AS prec_worth
FROM store t;
```

Comment: Thank You SO much. why did u added this 's' and 't' over there ?

Comment: You can remove them, they are actually aliases for inner and outer table in query. But they are of no use in this query so you can omit them.